# How to find and direct html back into the child of $(this). using JQuery Validator

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate, this

I have a webpage that generates a dynamic number of forms on it, all of which I'd like to parse with the same bit of jquery using the validator plugin.  Each form does contain a unique id value but I'm having trouble figuring out how to slip success and error comments back into the form output using $(this).  Here's a look at one of the forms:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <form id="form-04" role="form">
            <div name="form-status"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></div>
                    <input class="form-control" id="FromEmail" name="FromEmail" placeholder="Your Email Address" type="text">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <div class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope"></span></div>
                    <input class="form-control" id="ToEmail" name="ToEmail" placeholder="Your Friends Email Address" type="text">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <textarea class="form-control" id="Message" name="Message" placeholder="Your Message, 512 characters max." rows="5"></textarea>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" style="float: right;" type="submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here's a look at my validator code:

```
    $('#form-01, #form-02, #form-03, #form-04').each(function() {
    $(this).validate({
        rules: {
            FromEmail: {
                required: true,
                email: true,
                maxlength: 128
            },
            ToEmail: {
                required: true,
                email: true,
                maxlength: 128
            },
            Message: {
                required: true,
                maxlength: 512,
                badCharRegex: /^[^\<\>&#]+$/i
            }
        },
        messages: {
            FromEmail: {
                required: "Please enter a valid email address.",
                maxlength: "Please try to keep your email address to 128 characters or less."
            },
            ToEmail: {
                required: "Please enter a valid email address.",
                maxlength: "Please try to keep your email address to 128 characters or less."
            },
            Message: {
                required: "Please tell us what's on your mind.",
                maxlength: "Please try to keep your messages to 512 characters or less.",
                badCharRegex: "The following characters are not permitted in this form.  ( > < & # )  Please remove before submitting."
            },
        },
        submitHandler: function(form) {
            var request;
            // Abort any pending request.
            if (request) request.abort();
            var $inputs = $(form).find("input, select, textarea, button");
            var serializedData = $(form).serialize();
            // Disable the inputs for the duration of the ajax request.
            $inputs.prop("disabled", true);
            request = $.ajax({
                url: "/somefolder/ajax.php",
                cache: false,
                type: "post",
                data: serializedData
            });
            // Called on success.
            request.done(function(msg) {
                console.log(msg);
                if(msg == "1") {
                    /* insert success message back into form html */
                } else {
                    /* insert fail message back into form html */
                }
            });
            // Called on failure.
            request.fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                // log the error to the console
                $("div:first", this).html("The following error occured: " + textStatus, errorThrown);
            });
            // Called if the request failed or succeeded.
            request.always(function () {
                // reenable the inputs
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $inputs.prop("disabled", false);
                }, 2000);
            });
            // Prevent default posting of form.
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```

For now the form post fails simply because I haven't created the ajax.php template and all it's code yet but I'm trying to capture that error message and display it in the HTML of the form.

Here's the bit that I've been trying to figure out:

```
$("div:first", this).html("The following error occured: " + textStatus, errorThrown);
```

The code I posted in the line above doesn't work and I'm at my wits end on this stuff so how do I use the $(this). selector which is really id for "form-04" and tell it to move down one child to the div where the status should be displayed so I can insert a little dynamic html text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't make much sense to me yet but the solution turned out to be changing this:

```
$("div:first", this).html("The following error occured: " + textStatus, errorThrown);
```

to this:

```
$(form).find('[name="form-status"]').html("The following error occured: " + textStatus, errorThrown);
```

I guess the $(this).validator code at the top of my javascript ends up actually containing the form tag as well as all the other html within it.  Just wish their was an easy way to see this as debug output.